# How to have getc(stdin) to return ctrl characters?

Tags: c++, linux, terminal, termios

I'm trying to get a function that will return all character read in from the console, including ctrl characters such as ctrl-c. This is all in linux with c++.

However it currently doesn't return ctrl-c. I'm unsure if there is another terminal setting that will allow this.

Here's what I'm currently working with

```
int ttyGetChar() {
  struct termios newTerminalSettings;
  struct termios oldTerminalSettings;
  int result;

  tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldTerminalSettings); // get old settings
  newTerminalSettings = oldTerminalSettings; // Copy to set up new settings

  newTerminalSettings.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newTerminalSettings); // Apply the new settings

  result = getc(stdin); // read one character under new settings
  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldTerminalSettings); // Restore the old settings
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Checking the man page, I think perhaps you want to clear the `ISIG` bit in `c_lflag`?

Comment: @NateEldredge The issue is I still need to generate the signal. I have a signal handler in separate code, the issue is that I have to wait for ```getc(stdin)``` to return before I can process the results of the handler.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure that you can have your cake and eat it too.  Can you clear `ISIG` and then manually `raise(SIGINT)` if the character read was Ctrl-C?

Answer (score 0):

These are not characters, these are control events. I believe there is no standard way in C++ to "read" them, but platform-specific solutions exist. For example, in Windows, you have the `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` function to handle control events, and in Linux, they are sent as signals and can be captured using the `signal` or `sigaction` functions.